# Handling out of date state in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I am running into issues setting a state created with the 'useState' hook from within async functions.

I've created a codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/james-ohalloran/pen/ZdNwWQ

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increase = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    },1000);
  }

  const decrease = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    setCount(count - 1);
    },1000)
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
      <span className="count">{count}</span>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the above example, if you click 'increase' followed by 'decrease'..you will end up with -1 (I would expect it to be 0).
If this was a React class instead of a functional component, I would assume the solution would be to use `bind(this)` on the function, but I didn't expect this to be an issue with arrow functions.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(count) above the return statement ?

Comment: why are you using setTimeout?

Comment: I'm not actually using setTimout in my app. I'm awaiting for a network request to finish, and then changing the errors list. This is just a simpler example of the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found a solution. I didn't realize I'm able to reference the previousState from the useState setter function: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 0):

It is because of using `setTimeout`

Let's assume that you've called the `increase()` 10 times in a second.

`count` will be always `0`. Because the state is updated after a second, every `increment()` called in a second will have an unupdated `count`.

So every `increment()` will call `setCount(0 + 1);`.

So no matter how many times you call in a second, the `count` is always `1`.

Comment: Yeah I can confirm this is the behaviour I'm seeing when I log out count. How would you suggest restructuring it so that the code in the setTimeout callback can access the new state?